# creating a file uploader

Tags: java

I'm not a java programmer (I come from asp.net c#) but I'm considering writing a small java application to upload files. In my web app, the user needs to upload a spreadsheet to my server and I want to check the file size and extension before the upload. Most uploader seems overly bloated for what I'm looking to do and I want to build something really simple.

What do I need to do to make this? Eclipse seems to be the best IDE for java. What else do I need and how difficult would it be to write an uploader?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Commons Fileupload. http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Comment: Are you writing an uploader, or a webapp that you can upload files to?

Comment: @DaveNewton the way the question is phrased suggests that there already exists a web app that he wants to add client-side checking to.

Comment: Embedded in a web page or launched from a link?  Sand-boxed or trusted?  Any custom configuration required for the uploader (e.g. initial path)?  Any requirement to report back to the content pages?

Comment: Embedded in a webpage, trusted (in an https session), reports back to the page that the upload was complete

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been working on REST java ee webservices using Jersey (jax-rs). These allow you to define custom paths, accept and return types (ie text/xml, multipart, etc), methods (GET,POST,etc) and be just about has finely grained as you would like. I haven't done anything with file upload, but I found an example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/) to get you started. Jersey is a stable, growing, highly-extensible framework (did I mention it supports MVC) and that's why I'm suggesting that you adopt it. [Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html) is a tutorial to get you started with jax-rs, and of course there's always the [project site](http://jersey.java.net/) for reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Kind of overkill for a one-class servlet app, IMO, especially if they're new to Java.

Comment: And especially since OP was clearly asking for client side checking for an existing .NET app

Comment: In which part does he mention .NET? Except for his background.

Comment: Also he doesn't say it needs to be client side, just "before the upload." You can examine the supposed file path before opening the output stream. To comment on ease of use, I found doing annotations and jax-rs _extremely_ easy compared to servlets.

Comment: I just need a little java applet that the client downloads to his browser and that handles checking the file size and uploading to the ASP.NET server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to steer you away from Java, but you should be able to check file size and extension with javascript.  That should only be a dozen or less lines of javascript and should be pretty fast (runtime) since an applet doesn't have to load.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance (I am not a javascript guy),but how exactly in JavaScript you check file size and name?

Comment: ok, it can check file name; but don't think it can check file size

Comment: Javascript can't access the file system!